# How do I fix an ignored update file in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: apt

When I am in Terminal and I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get ignored files.

What are these, and how do I fix them?

Comment: What file, update of what?

Comment: please post some output and the commands you used to update.

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: My source list was the files that were ignored

Comment: Please re-run `sudo apt-get update >> logfile 2>&1` which will create _logfile_ to show us what is being ignored. Then, please edit your question and include the pertinent parts of _logfile_.

Comment: N: Ignoring file 'teejee2008-ppa-raring.list.save.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.36.158263' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Answer (score 1):

```
N: Ignoring directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension  
N: Ignoring file '90rkhunter.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.52.459330' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension  
N: Ignoring file '90rkhunter.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.36.158263' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension  
N: Ignoring file '99-localepurge.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.52.459330'
```

While I can't say why it is issuing a Notice (that's the `N:`) on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` (ignoring it is right, issuing the notice is not), it should be reasonably obvious that the other files are being ignored for not having the right filename extension, as they appear to be backups. Removing these files should solve the problem, and may get rid of all the notices if the directory one is simply occurring because there are invalid files within it.

Running the following code (all one line) will permanently remove these backups, and hopefully fix your problem.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.52.459330 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.36.158263 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-localepurge.before_restore_2013-12-08_17.40.52.459330
```